# Passing taps to the filter using file in gnuradio

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I'm trying to pass 2000 taps to the fft filter in gnuradio. How can i read file and pass it to the fft filter tap filed?

Comment: 2000 Taps is **massive**. In 90% of cases where I asked people whether they'd actually need a filter that massive, it turned out they didn't, but just generated a filter that was way, way stricter than the application actually demanded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done. However you can use the `Filter Taps` variables available in the `GRC` to produce the desired taps at the initialization of your flowgraph. Pass the `ID` of the variable at the `taps` field of your `FFT filter` block and you are done.

If your taps are very specific and cannot be constructed from the available filter taps variable, you could possibly edit the generated python file and use a python array to store them.

**EDIT:** As @Marcus noted you can use `numpy` to load taps from a file. Just use the `Import` element from the `GRC` to import `numpy` and then using a `Variable` element, use `numpy.fromfile('filename')` to load the desired taps.

Comment: Not fully agreeing with this; one could think of a workaround that uses an `import numpy` block, and then use `numpy.fromfile(…)` in the taps field!

Comment: Yeah, good solution. However, I think that he just needs the already existing ways to produce the taps. 2000 taps is way to large to be practical.

Comment: Re: 2000 taps. True. But, there might be some special usage that demands a specific filter – and honestly, if you got the time or the CPU power, the multithreaded FFT filters do pack a punch and can make dealing with these filter lengths feasible – if the numerical stability allows (FFT is pretty stable, though).

Comment: Of course. Depends always the application, however. If it is real-time, I think that such a big filter becomes prohibitive for sampling rates above few hundred KSPS. For off-line use,  it may worth waiting to finish the processing. But I think, in 99% of the cases, people just get taps from a tool without having in mind or fully understand the computational effort that is required.

Comment: Ha! As if! Start GRC; build: 
constant source -> FFT Filter (real taps, taps=range(2000), one thread) -> probe rate -> message debug. My machine does ~70MS/s with that!

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I can go 46 MS/S. Perhaps I remembered the FIR that at the same taps scores 900 KS/s. Wow!

Comment: hi guys .... thanks a lot for such information, actuly I'm working with 100MHz sampling frequency in my application so after the calculation i found out that i need 2000 taps for the filter. and i wanna make my application work in real time as much as possible.

Comment: 100MS/s with a 2000 tap filter?  Nope. Nope nope nope nope. Improve your filter, reduce its complexity.

Answer (score 0):

I had good luck with this:

1. in Matlab create your vector of taps
2. if `h` is your vector with the taps, print them to a file with these instructions:

> ```
> fileID = fopen('filter_taps.txt', 'w');`
> fprintf(fileID, '[%5.3f]+', h);
> fclose(fileID);
> ```

3. open the text file with a simple text editor and remove the last "+"
4. Now, go over to the gnuradio-companion and open an Interpolating FIR filter block
5. highlight and copy the taps from your text file [0.00]+[0.01]+... etc (I used control+c)
6. in the "taps" field of the GRC FIR block, paste the taps (I used control+v)

Disclosure: I run Matlab on my Windows laptop, and I run GRC on my Linux (Ubuntu) laptop.